# Radial navigation: enlarge the space between the list elements

Tags: html, css, scale

i'm working on this element http://zag-test.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/

what i need is to "enalrge" the entire element in the **same position**, but via CSS i can on enlarge the central button (CLICK button).

How can i solve?

CSS

```
.cn-button {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 50%;
z-index: 11;
margin-top: -2.25em;
margin-left: -3.78em;
padding-top: 0em;
width: 7.5em;
height: 7.5em;
border: none;
border-radius: 50%;
background: none;
background-color: #000;
color: #f9d70a;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 1.3em;
text-transform: uppercase;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the transform attribute with scale to make everything bigger:

```
#cn-wrapper {
    transform: scale(1.4) !important;
}
```

This is for the outer menu options, and the !important forces it to be used

Comment: thank you so much! can i ask you more? How can i change the background of the "Click button"? I'm tryiong but nothing happens... I added the CSS into the first post

Comment: change it to what? color? image? gradient? @NOW_Antonio

Comment: i want to tadd an Image :)

Comment: well what have you tried? background-image:url('image.jpg') worked for me

Comment: i'm trying the same, but doest not works for me.. I just added an image in the first post, you can see the result :)

Comment: what if you remove background:none a couple of rows higher @NOW_Antonio

Comment: i've tryied but nothing happens :/

Comment: well, does the image exist at that location? check you network traffic if it loads OK. You should probably post a new question for this issue

Comment: yes the location is correct. But yes, maybe i will create a new discussion for it